# Get Sub strings from Regex Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to get "North" and "6544789" strings separately from "North-6544789-Input.csv" by using Regex pattern. Could you please guide me to get Regex pattern for this string.

Comment: why not simply `var items = 'North-6544789-Input.csv'.split("-")` and `item[0]` is North and `item[1]` is  6544789

Comment: Are there more such example with some complex pattern? If not, then the comment above has a simple answer for you.

Comment: Please don't use regex for simple strings like what you have, unless you are obliged to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-.*
```

`\1` is `North`, `\2` is `6544789`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA3aI9/3)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response .You save my day!. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply try

```js
var items = 'North-6544789-Input.csv'.split("-");

alert( "first item - " + items[0] ); 

alert( "second item - " + items[1] );
```